# how to improve list generator function

Tags: python

the purpose of the below function is to return:

```
> f(0) returns [], 
> f(1) returns [[1]]
> f(2) returns [[1], [1,2]] 
> f(3) returns [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
```

how can it be improved?

```
def list_generator(number: int) -> list:
    if number == 0:
        new_list = []
    else:
        temp_list = []
        new_list = [0] * number
        for idx, num in zip(range(len(new_list)), range(1, number + 1)):
            temp_list.append(num)
            new_list[idx] = list(set(temp_list))

    return new_list
```

Comment: If you have code that works but you're looking for feedback or optimizations, [codereview.se] is probably a better place to ask but remember to read their [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page first

Comment: FYI your function uses the variable name `int` which is a python builtin type. Assigning the variable name `int` clobbers that type, which may break your code in unexpected ways. Use `_int` or `num` or something else that is not a builtin.

Comment: @danielhoherd it doesn't, that's a type annotation

Comment: What the improvement is ? speed ? memory ? reduced code ? easy read ? easy maintenance ? or else ?

Comment: @Anentropic d'oh, good catch. Should've waited until both my eyes were open to review code 

Answer (score 4):

```
def f(n):
    return [[x + 1 for x in range(i)] for i in range(1, n + 1)]

for n in range(6):
    print(n, f(n))
# 0 []
# 1 [[1]]
# 2 [[1], [1, 2]]
# 3 [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
# 4 [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
# 5 [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
def f(number: int) -> list:
    return [list(range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, number+1)]
```

Comment: Having witnessed the debugging process for this code in realtime, I'm sad that it's not giving me the option to see the full edit history.

Comment: @Samwise "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."